# How to access widgets from another Dynamic Class in kv?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Is there a way to access a widget from another Dynamic Class in Kivy? I'm trying to trigger some event from a dynamic class which is going to have an effect on a other dynamic class.

Here's an example:

**Python:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_file("ui version control/dropdowns_and_buttons.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("main_ui.kv")

MyApp().run()
```

The **main_ui.kv file:**

```
MDGridLayout:
    dropdown_default: "-- Select --"
    cols: 2
    size_hint: 1, 0.3
    pos_hint: {"center": (0.5, 0.65)}
    spacing: 30

    DropdownMenu:
        id: name_menu
        text: root.dropdown_default
        color: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7) if self.text == root.dropdown_default else app.theme_cls.text_color
        values: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
        on_text: self.text

    DropdownMenu:
        id: number_menu
        text: root.dropdown_default
        color: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7) if self.text == root.dropdown_default else app.theme_cls.text_color
        values: [f"{i}" for i in range(1, 46)]
        on_text: self.text
```

And an additional **dropdowns_and_buttons.kv file** having custom dropdown widget and button in a separate kv file

```
<DropdownMenu@Spinner>:
    dropdown_cls: Factory.CustomDropdown
    option_cls: Factory.DropdownOptions
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 0.4
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [6]
        Color: 
            rgba: 0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5
        Line:
            width: 1
            rounded_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 6, 6, 6, 6, 100

    MDLabel:
        id: dd_label
        text: "Changing text"
        center_x: root.center_x + 110
        center_y: root.center_y

<DropdownOptions@SpinnerOption>:
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0                           
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6
        Line:
            width: 1
            points: self.x+10, self.y, self.width-10, self.y

<CustomDropdown@DropDown>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 0.4
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [0, 0, 6, 6]
    on_dismiss: print(root.DropdownMenu.ids.dd_label.text)
```

I'm trying to use `dd_label` widget from `DropdownMenu` class in `CustomDropdown` class. So far, I can access it using `app.root.ids.name_menu.ids.dd_label` on `on_dismiss` but, I feel like it's not an ideal way to go about it.

Now, I know `on_dismiss` will throw an error because it's not accessing the intended widget `MDLabel` from `DropdownMenu` class.

Can someone help me figure out how I can access `dd_label` widget from `CustomDropdown` class?

Comment: watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSMzCsnocn0&t=4s

Comment: This explains accessing widgets from other classes, but I'm trying to learn how we can access widgets from dynamic class. Like I explained in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way. To use widgets from other dynamic class, I needed to use `Factory` to create an instance of `DropdownMenu` in `CustomDropdown` class.

Like this: `on_dismiss: print(Factory.DropdownMenu().ids.dd_label.text)`

Comment: That's not correct, you are creating a new instance of the class, the text is going to be the default value here, not the current value of your existing widget.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I can make the text change (modify widget from `DropdownMenu`) when `on_dismiss` is triggered. In this case, I want the `MDLabel` text to be the default one and I want the text to change only when the `on_dismiss` is triggered.

Comment: I mean calling Factory.DropDownMenu() will create a new menu, not the existing one, if you are doing all that for a value you already know (because it's the text of dd_label that never changes) that that just looks like long detour.

Comment: Oh, that is just for reference, I was actually trying to animate the widget when the `DropDown` closes. If there's a shorter way to achieve it, please let me know. And besides, I was just learning how we can access widgets from other Dynamic classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `attach_to` property of the `DropDown` class, which will reference the `Spinner`/`DropDownMenu` instance.

`on_select: print(self.attach_to.ids.dd_label.text)`.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html?highlight=dropdown#kivy.uix.dropdown.DropDown.attach_to

Comment: It's throwing an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids'`

Comment: ah, i missed the value is reset to None before dispatching the on_dismiss event, using `on_select` instead should be almost equivalent and avoid the issue.

Comment: Yes, but it's not going to be triggered if the user closes the `DropDown` without selecting anything right? And I don't want that. I wanna trigger something in `MDLabel` widget when the `DropDown` closes.

Comment: I wanna pass `MDLabel` widget to a function when the `DropDown` closes regardless of which the user selects or closes the `DropDown` without selecting anything.